# JMeter and WebDriver Set - do not work

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I've encountered problems with starting JMeter and WebDriver Set.

I set - as in http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/ - `Thread Group` with:

```
jp@gc FF Driver Config
jp@gc Web Driver Sampler
View Results in Table
```

In Web Driver Sampler I have following lines:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://google.com')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

And I get following error:

```
 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory
```

Switching to Chrome does not solve the problem, I get the very same error.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 22):

- Download zip from jmeter-plugins.org
- Copy jar files into lib & lib/ext directories
- Delete older / Duplicate http jars from [apache-jmeter-2.13\lib]

  1. httpclient-4.2.6.jar (delete this jar)
  2. httpclient-4.3.1.jar
  3. httpcore-4.2.5.jar (delete this jar)
  4. httpcore-4.3.jar
  5. httpmime-4.2.6.jar (delete this jar)
  6. httpmime-4.3.1.jar

  now it will work fine

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck for this for a few hours until I found your post.

Comment: I was stuck on this also.  Just got it to work now.  Removing this older jar versions solved the problem.  It must be conflicting.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There were few libraries (httpclient*-4.4.jar) in different versions, I removed old ones and it works:)